# Copy entire column including formatting to a variable number of adjacent columns in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Jeeped kindly provided the following *with..end with* solution to copying one column (Column C) a variable number of times within the same worksheet. However, the code overwrites Column C and doesn't copy the formats. I've attempted to adapt the code but have been unsuccessful.
   Any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
Dim rangeCopy As Range
Dim Addcol As Integer

Set rangeCopy = sht02AnalysisSummary.Range("C:C")

Addcol = NrEvaluated  '(the variable taken from userform input)

With sht02AnalysisSummary
    Set rangeCopy = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    rangeCopy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Resize(rangeCopy.Rows.Count, Addcol)
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tweak effectively 'moves right one cell' after it's found the right-most column:

```
rangeCopy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rangeCopy.Rows.Count, Addcol)
```

Swap the above out for your existing `rangeCopy.Copy` line.

Also, you've no need to keep the first `Set rangeCopy = sht02AnalysisSummary.Range("C:C")` line - this can be removed.

Comment: Excellent. That's sorted the overwriting.  I can sort the formatting...or if I can't I'll be back looking through this website's FAQs or asking questions.